# List doesn't appear and elif statement doesn't activate

Tags: python

In my text RPG I have the attack function set up like this

```
def attack(self):

    spell = [magic_spell for magic_spell in self.spell_book if isinstance(magic_spell,magic.Spell)]
    if not spell:
        print("You have no spells to cast!")
    
    input('What do you want to attack with? Melee or Magic: ')

    if input == str('magic'):
        for i, magic_spell in enumerate(spell, 1):
            print('Choose a spell to cast:')
            print(f"{i}. {spell}")
        
        valid =False
        while not valid:
            choice = input("")
            try:
                if player.mana == 0:
                    print("You dont have enough mana")
                else:   
                    room = world.tile_at(self.x,self.y)
                    enemy = room.enemy
                    print("You use {} against {}!".format(spell,enemy.name))
                    enemy.hp -=  spell.damage
                    self.mana = self.mana - spell.mana

                    if not enemy.is_alive():
                        print("You killed {}!".format(enemy.name))
                        
                    else:
                        print("{} HP is {}.".format(enemy.name,enemy.hp))
            except(ValueError,IndexError):
                print("Invalid choice, try again")      
    elif input == str('melee'):
        best_weapon = self.most_powerful_weapon()
        room = world.tile_at(self.x,self.y)
        enemy = room.enemy
        print("You use {} against {}!".format(best_weapon.name,enemy.name))
        enemy.hp -=  best_weapon.damage

        if not enemy.is_alive():
            print("You killed {}!".format(enemy.name))
            
        else:
            print("{} HP is {}.".format(enemy.name,enemy.hp))
```

The list spell part of the function doesn't appear when you type `magic` into the prompt. The list spells function is directly modeled after my `heal` function, but of course instead of healing you are doing damage with the selected spell.

```
def heal(self):
    consumables = [item for item in self.inventory if isinstance(item,items.Consumables)]
    if not consumables:
        print("You dont have any items to heal you!")
        return 

    for i, item in enumerate(consumables, 1):
        print("Choose an item to use to heal: ")
        print("{}. {}".format(i, item))
    
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        choice = input("")
        try:
            to_eat = consumables[int(choice)-1]
            self.hp = min(100,self.hp + to_eat.healing_value)
            self.inventory.remove(to_eat)
            print("Current HP: {}".format(self.hp))
            valid = True
        except (ValueError,IndexError):
            print("Invalid choice, try again")
```

I am stumped as to why the `heal` function will work but the `attack` doesn't. Entering melee also doesn't perform the melee attack.

Comment: No need to write `str('magic')`. You can just use `'magic'`. Also, see [Which String Formatting Method Should You Use?](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#which-string-formatting-method-should-you-use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` is a built-in function and it is not recommended to use it like a variable.

But the main error in your code is that you do not store the input in variable.

Use this:

`user_input = input("What do you want to attack with? Melee or Magic: ")`